# Can all matrices be decomposed as product of right and left eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Given $N\times N$ matrix $A$，I see a formula in literature without saying other requirements

$$A= \sum_{i}\lambda_i R^T_i L_i $$
where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalue and $R_i$ and $L_i$ are right and left eigenvector with eigenvalue of $\lambda_i$.

I'm confused about this formula. First I didn't see this formula in my linear algebra course. Second there are so much ambiguities in this formula: What's about $A$ that is non-diagonalizable, i.e. eigenvector's number is less than the eigenvalues' number? What's about there are degenercy in some $\lambda_i$ so how to pair $R_i$ and $L_i$?

So where can I find the complete statement of this formula? What's the name of this decomposion?

Comment: You will need to give context here. The formula is obviously not true in general, as there there are nonzero matrices with all eigenvalues zero.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm also curious about the prerequisite of this formula. So I want to find someone who saw the formula and tell me the name of this formula.

Comment: With eigenvalues, it makes no sense to me. If the $\lambda_i $ were the singular values, then it would look like the singular value decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

The quoted formula is actually equivalent to the usual [eigenvalue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of a matrix $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$, so it only works for diagonalisable matrices. Let me explain this below.

As pointed out by Martin Argerami, the formula uses a weird convention where both $\mathbf{L}_i$ and $\mathbf{R}_i$ are row vectors; for convenience, let me change $\mathbf{R}_i$ into column vectors. Define the matrices $\mathbf{X}_L$ whose rows comprise the left eigenvectors, and $\mathbf{X}_R$ whose columns comprise the right eigenvectors:
$$\mathbf{X}_L = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{L}_1 \\ \mathbf{L}_2 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}, \quad
\mathbf{X}_R = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{R}_1 & \mathbf{R}_2 ... \end{pmatrix}.
$$
I now argue that the quoted formula is equivalent to $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{X}_R \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{X}_L$. To see this, write out the matrix element
$$\begin{aligned}
A_{ij} &= \sum_{kl} (X_R)_{ik} \Lambda_{kl} (X_L)_{lj}\\
       &= \sum_{kl} (R_k)_i \lambda_k \delta_{kl} (L_l)_j\\
       &= \sum_k (R_k)_i \lambda_k (L_k)_j,
\end{aligned}$$
where in the second line, I used the definition of $\mathbf{\Lambda}$, $\mathbf{X}_L$ and $\mathbf{X}_R$. The last line is just the matrix elements obtained from the quoted formula.

Having shown that the formula is equivalent to $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{X}_R \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{X}_L$, I now use the known result that the left and right eigenvectors are biorthogonal, so we can always normalise them such that $\mathbf{X}_L \mathbf{X}_R = \mathbf{I}$. With this choice of normalisation, we have $\mathbf{X}_L = \mathbf{X}_R^{-1}$ since for finite dimensions, $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{I} \implies \mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{I}$. Thus, the quoted formula is equivalent to $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{X}_R \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{X}_R^{-1}$. Hence, we recover the usual spectral decomposition with $\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{X}_R$.

With regards to the other parts of your question:

- The formula doesn't work for non-diagonalisable matrices.
- Even when there is degeneracy, you can still choose the basis in the degenerate subspace for both left and right eigenvectors that preserves the biorthogonality. Use that basis when pairing $\mathbf{L}_i$ and $\mathbf{R}_i$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the formula makes no sense (at least for an arbitrary matrix). But it heavily resembles the [Singular Value Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

There is another oddity in the formula you wrote, in that it seems to write vectors as horizontal matrices; this is really odd because then it forces you to write the usual "matrix times vector" as $Ax^T$.

The Singular Value Decomposition is $A=UDV$, where $U,V$ are unitaries (orthogonal if your matrix is real) and $D$ is diagonal with the singular values in the diagonal. If $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the canonical basis, we can write 
$$
D=\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j\,e_je_j^T.
$$
Thus
$$
A=\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j\,Ue_j\, (Ve_j)^T=\sum_{j=1}^n\sigma_j\, x_jy_j^T,
$$
where $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are two orthonormal bases.